# CSS Constantly Refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website works fine on desktop browsers, but on mobile devices (iOS, Android, etc.) it will reload the background and seemingly refresh the whole page anytime I zoom in or out. I was wondering what might be causing this, but up to this point, I've been unable to locate the cause of the problem. It makes mobile browsing very irritating.

http://www.zombiesquirrel.com

All the CSS and JavaScript files should be linked in the source of my page. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: You have an error with something `touchwipe` maybe that's the problem... Also, Something happens on Chrome when you open devtools, the slider goes crazy for a few secs.

Comment: I'm not experiencing the occurrence when I open Chrome devtools, but I know that there is an error in touchwipe. I'm not really sure what the error is but if it could cause the problem, I'll dig a bit further.

Comment: Ah I fixed the `touchwipe` issue, it was a simple fix. Looks like my friend may have just removed the link to the JS file...That being said, it didn't fix the issue, but thanks for bringing it up as it made me take another look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The issue was in the following CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color:black;
}


div.back3
{

background-image:url("back.png");
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
margin-left:-2%;
margin-top:-100%;
padding:0;
height:400%;
width:104%;
} 

div.back2
{

background-image:url("back.png");
background-position:250px 250px;
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
margin-left:-2%;
margin-top:-28%;
padding:0;
height:400%;
width:104%;
}

div.main
{
position:static;
}
```

I'm not sure exactly which part of this caused the problem, I'll do some more digging, but for now I simply used the following to specify that this CSS stylesheet only be used on non-mobile devices:

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/z/styles/main-style.css' media='screen and (min-device-width:770px)'>`

The min-device-width property is set to that high a number to make sure the iPad also doesn't use this stylesheet (though I may run into problems if machines are close to the iPad size, but this stylesheet isn't super critical to my site's operation anyway).

Thanks!
EDIT: Special thanks to Andrew Manson for the suggestion of disabling the stylesheet only for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked on my iPhone, I see what you are talking about, however I don't see the page reloading itself, it may just reload the CSS to adjust to the new size.

If you are trying to enable easy mobile viewing you should create a mobile stylesheet and use javascript and php to change the css stylesheet.

Comment: Once I found which stylesheet was causing the problem, I used your advice to exclude it for mobile devices. I used the following line, as indicated in the answer I posted.
`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/z/styles/main-style.css' media='screen and (min-device-width:770px)'>`

Comment: Yes thank you, I had to wait a day to accept my own answer though.